# Why a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ can be generated by three vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

https://www.assignmentexpert.com/homework-answers/mathematics/linear-algebra/question-66803

In this example question (and also some other questions I saw), they all mentioned 'the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ generated by three vectors'. I'm confused about this statement because I think three vectors can only span $\mathbb{R}^3$ or a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ but not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

And also in the solution, there are three bases, which also confuses me as I think the number of bases of an $\mathbb{R}^4$ space should always be 4.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Even if $Span\{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0)\}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^3$, it's not equal to $\mathbb R^3$ and is a subspace of $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: I thought the dimension of a space is decided by the number of its bases but not the number of elements in each basis vector (i.e. the dimension of the basis vector). Was I correct about this? And like in the case you mentioned, if (1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0) are the bases of a space then what should be the dimension of it, three or four?

Comment: You are right, it is the number of basis vectors, say, $e_1,e_2,e_3$ for a basis of $\Bbb R^3$. But this is a **subspace** generated by $e_1,e_2,e_3$ of $\Bbb R^4$, which has a basis $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde But I still don't get why in the example question, the answer of the set of orthonormal bases only have 3 basis vectors when they are still the bases of a subspace of $\mathbb{R^4}$.

Comment: Because a subspace of dimension $3$ in $\Bbb R^4$ has a basis with only $3$ basis vectors by definition. You have to review the definition of a vector subspace, right? The subspace has dimension $3$, and not $4$.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand your confusion.

Given any vector space, you may take any number of vectors in it and produce a subspace by forming their linear span, which is the set of all linear combinations of vectors in the family.

This can, for example, be applied to the case of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^4$ and any three vectors in it: the span of these vectors will create a subspace of dimension at most 3, which will then be "isomorphic" to the corresponding $\mathbb{R}^n$ space of the same dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Three vectors can span a subspace in any ($\Bbb R$-)vector space $V$ (provided that there *are* three vectors in that vector space; this is always the case for $V=\Bbb R^n$ when $n\ge1$). The subspace spanned by those three vectors may be described as $$\operatorname{Span}(v_1,v_2,v_3):=\left\{h\in V\,:\, \exists \alpha_1\in\Bbb R,\exists \alpha_2\in\Bbb R,\exists\alpha_3\in\Bbb R,\, h=\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\alpha_3v_3\right\}$$

The vectors being three in number is not particularly relevant.